# Get constants, functions, and protocols from global scope by name

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

## Background

I'm implementing an interface to allow JavaScript to call Objective-C APIs. I'm writing my code in Obj-C++, so can equally use Obj-C or C++ approaches.

Given a string to look up, such as `@"NSObject"`, it's possible to retrieve the class by that name:

```objectivec
// Where `lookupString` is an NSString* such as @"NSObject".
Class clazz = NSClassFromString(lookupString);
```

I would similarly like to be able to retrieve constants, functions, enums (all data types, really) from the global scope. There are many of these, for example in Foundation:

```
// 1) A constant (or standalone enumerated value)
// @see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1497293-string_encodings/nsasciistringencoding?language=objc
NSASCIIStringEncoding = 1

// 2) An actual enum
// @see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstringencodingconversionoptions/
typedef enum {
    NSAllowLossyEncodingConversion = 1,
    NSExternalRepresentationEncodingConversion = 2
} NSStringEncodingConversionOptions;

// 3) A function
// @see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395298-nsstringfromprotocol?language=objc
NSString * NSStringFromProtocol(Protocol *proto);

// 4) A protocol
// @see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnectiondatadelegate?language=objc
@protocol NSURLConnectionDataDelegate
```

I am aware of these other obj-c runtime utilities:

- [NSSelectorFromString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395294-nsselectorfromstring?language=objc) (does this solve case #3?)
- [NSProtocolFromString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395147-nsprotocolfromstring?language=objc) (clearly solves case #4)

## Question

Can all four cases be solved? In other words, how can each of these data types be retrieved from the global scope (or in the scope of an explicitly-named library) at runtime by name alone?

Comment: I think dlsym would do the job for functions: https://gist.github.com/yellowbyte/ec470d75ba7c14ebefed271c6fe58e9e.

Comment: @EmmaLabbé Thanks! I think that functions may be covered more easily by `NSProtocolFromString` already, though. I'll have to read up on lower-level approaches like `dlsym`, though am hoping to manage somehow with just the APIs that the Obj-C runtime itself offers.